# PostgreSQL Regex: Until dot

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I got an table with dot-separated string-entries, eg.

1. "school.parent.child-1.petA"
2. "school.parent.child-1.petB"
3. "school.parent.child-1.petB.name"
4. "school.parent.child-1"
5. "school.parent.child-2"

Now I want to **get entry 4 and 5 but not 1, 2 or 3** with Regex using the information "school.parent"

("WHERE str ~* '...'" is necessary)

What I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE str ~* 'school.parent.\w*$'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE str ~* 'school.parent.*\.'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE str ~* 'school.parent.+?(?=\.)'
```

Closest was 'school.parent.+?(?=.)' which gave me 1,2,3 but not 4,5 (inverse)

Entries are only examples...could be any "string.string.string..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple method using `like`:

```
where str like 'school.parent.%' and
      str not like 'school.parent.%.%'
```

If you want a regular expression:

```
where str ~ '^school.parent.[^.]+$'
```

Based on your sample data, case insensitivity doesn't seem necessary.